# Need to set a one-off date range for SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, range

I have here part of a working script that runs to retrieve data from `<yesterday>` as shown here:

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @beginDate datetime, @endDate datetime, @itemCount int, @total decimal(10,2)
SET @beginDate = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
SET @endDate = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
--PRINT @beginDate
--PRINT @endDate
```

I want to run this for a one-off result to collect data that was missed during a server migration.

I have tried this:

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @beginDate datetime, @endDate datetime, @itemCount int, @total decimal(10,2)
SET @beginDate = '11/11/2015'
SET @endDate = '11/30/2015'
--PRINT @beginDate
--PRINT @endDate
```

But it did not seem to work properly. I wonder if I have the @beginDate and @endDate formatted correctly. Please advise.

Comment: What is your question?  Are you getting an error?  What does "did not seem to work properly" mean?

Comment: --> The result is the same as running the query assigned to <yesterday>

Comment: I saved the modification but it does not change the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SET @beginDate = '20151111'
SET @endDate= '20151130'
```

Comment: Same result. Maybe my methodology is incorrect? Saving the changes in SQL query, also saving to the Stored Procedure my process is referencing. Is there a better way to apply changes?

Comment: This was a shot in the blind actually. Few other variables that affect the result of your query, that is how you save on to the stored proc and what parameters provided. If you are doing select statement, you can copy the whole select statement and execute it as a one off script and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Yes this is correct. I needed to save to the correct location and Save As as well to get it to stick. Not sure what that's about, but the data is right. Thank you very much.